# Environment data can be seen using devTools with VueJS framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Right now, i have a project that using VueJS and VITE (All is latest version in 2024). I put my API key in Environment file or .env. But, when i open devTools, the key was showing. I don't think that suppose to do that. Maybe i'm doing something wrong, but for me, i already stuck, can you help me to solved this problem?

Btw, my .env file in the same path as package.json or package-lock.json.

[This is the .env path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvjZ3.png)

[This is what inside on .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxqHY.png)

[This is the leaks API key that suppose to be secret or doesn't to be showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGq8H.png)

The .env file does not show anything in their file to any one, especially not to cilent-side or devTools like that.